# javascript tweet status update

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

Ok so I thought I would find the answer I was looking for with a search but maybe I'm just not understanding things, so here goes.

I want to run status updates to my twitter account using javascript only my code runs on top of node.js so there is no html or php strictly javascript. So a text box is out php is out.

I've searched around and can't seem to find a solid example where I can just post using ajax or something to update my status can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Mikeal's [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module.  You can send a POST request as follows:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
  url: 'https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    status: "Your new Twitter status"
  })
}, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

Note that this example is not complete as you would still have to authenticate to Twitter.

Comment: I think this site may be a good resource for you: http://moonlitscript.com/post.cfm/how-to-use-oauth-and-twitter-in-your-node-js-expressjs-app/

Comment: @mcgrailm Request automatically "remembers" the cookies, so if you send the user & pass and you auth, you will remain auth for subsequent requests (note: things get more complicated if site's using captcha).